# installing PHP mysql extension in RHEL

Tags: php, mysql, linux, installation

Mysql is not working with PHP (each of them OK individually, Mysql OK with perl).

I've added `extension=mysql.so` to `php.ini`

After searching on the internet, I've tried those two commands

```
yum install php php-mysql httpd
yum install php-mysql php-gd
```

However, this results in:

```
mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 from rhel-i386-server-5 has depsolving problems
--> mysql conflicts with MySQL-server
Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql-server and mysql-devel.

Comment: Thanks, but I had actually done it already (both are included in the binary distribution of MySQL 5 for RHEL5 on i386.

Comment: @Quang-TuanLuong Is the daemon running?

Comment: @quitch Which process would that be ?

Comment: @Quang-TuanLuong mysqld. If so try restarting it.

Comment: @quitch sure, mysqld OK, can connect with Perl DBI

Answer (score 0):

here's a small checklist>

- have mysql service up and running.

> service mysql status
>
> ```
> service mysqld status
> ```

- have installed php-mysql extension

> yum install php-mysql

- have your mysql.so or mysqli.so in the extensions folder, you can find this in phpinfo() in extensions dir, in my case>

> extension_dir    /usr/lib64/php/modules

- check permissions for .so files I think -rwxr-xr-x.  is a nice practice.
- restart apache so it can reload php.ini

> service httpd restart

then, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It is noted that php-mysql (the PHP MySQL extension) has been replaced by php-mysqlnd.